# Count multiple rows in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have this table called Online_Transaction and i want to show all the types of transactions and how many where made of each type (completed,rejected,pending for authorization) in a specific month. I have this query until now but I get repeated results any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID ,
    YEAR(CREATED_ON) AS YEAR ,
    MONTH(CREATED_ON) AS MONTH ,
    ( SELECT
          Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID)
      FROM
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION
      WHERE
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID = 'COMPLETED' AND MONTH(CREATED_ON) = '2' ) AS COMPLETED ,
    ( SELECT
          Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID)
      FROM
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION
      WHERE
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID = 'DECLINED' AND MONTH(CREATED_ON) = '2' ) AS DECLINED ,
    ( SELECT
          Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID)
      FROM
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION
      WHERE
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID = 'FAILED' AND MONTH(CREATED_ON) = '2' ) AS FAILED ,
    ( SELECT
          Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID)
      FROM
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION
      WHERE
          ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID = 'PENDING_AUTH' AND MONTH(CREATED_ON) = '2' ) AS PENDING_AUTH
--(SELECT Count(*) from )
FROM
    ONLINE_TRANSACTION
WHERE
    MONTH(CREATED_ON) = '2'
GROUP BY
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID ,
    ONLINE_TRANSACTION.CREATED_ON
```

And I get these results:

```
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID                  YEAR        MONTH       COMPLETED   DECLINED    FAILED      
------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------
INSURANCE--TYPE                       2009        2           9712        177         0           
CHEQUEBOOK-TYPE                       2009        2           9712        177         0           
CHEQUE-STOP-YPE                       2009        2           9712        177         0           
PAYMENT-TRANS-TYPE               2009        2           9712        177         0           
DOMESTIC-TRANSFER-TYPE                2009        2           9712        177         0
PAYMENT-TRANS-TYPE                2009        2           9712        177         0           
INTRA-ACCOUNT-TRANS-TYPE              2009        2           9712        177         0           
INTRA-BANK-TRANS-TYPE                 2009        2           9712        177         0           
STANDING-ORDER-TYPE                   2009        2           9712        177         0           
STATEMENT-REORDERING TYPE             2009        2           9712        177         0           
PAYMENTS-TRANS-TYPE             2009        2           9712        177         0
```

As you can see the results are repeated, wheres in the table it should be different values.
Any ideas?

---

Having tried the answers below  this is what I get:
 this type of results set- it displays different results for each transaction type in different rows so if say the transaction type is Intra-transfer and i has 10 completed and 2 rejected it will show the completed in one row and the rejected in another row? how do your show it in one row per transaction type

```
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID        YEAR MONTH REJECTED COMPLETED POSTED

ALPHA-INSURANCE-TRANS-TYPE  2009 2       0 12 0 
CHEQUEBOOK-ORDER-TRANS-TYPE 2009 2      0 0 0 
CHEQUEBOOK-ORDER-TRANS-TYPE 2009 2      0 52 0 
CHEQUEBOOK-ORDER-TRANS-TYPE 2009 2      2 0 0 
CHEQUE-STOP-TRANS-TYPE      2009 2      0 3 0
 PAYMENT-TRANS-TYPE         2009 2     0 361 0 
PAYMENT-TRANS-TYPE          2009 2     1 0 0 
DOMESTIC-TRANSFER-TRANS-TYPE 2009 2    0 0 0 
DOMESTIC-TRANSFER-TRANS-TYPE 2009 2   0 541 0 
DOMESTIC-TRANSFER-TRANS-TYPE 2009 2    6 0 0
```

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID ,
    YEAR(CREATED_ON) AS YEAR ,
    MONTH(CREATED_ON) AS MONTH ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-REJECTED ' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS REJECTED ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-COMPLETED ' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS COMPLETED ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-DECLINDED ' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS DECLINED ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-FAILED' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS FAILED ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-PENDING-AUTH ' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS PENDING_AUTH ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-PENDING-POST ' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS PENDING_POST ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'STATUS-TRANS-PENDING' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS PENDING ,
    SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID
          WHEN 'ALPHA-STATUS-TRANS-POSTED' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) AS POSTED
FROM
    ONLINE_TRANSACTION
WHERE
    MONTH(CREATED_ON) = '2'
GROUP BY
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID ,
    YEAR(CREATED_ON) ,
    MONTH(CREATED_ON) ,
    STATUS_ID
```

Comment: @Alex: What did you use for table formatting?

Comment: @Alex: that's what i am trying to figure out? block quote?

Comment: problem is as above i get repeating rows for empty results

Answer (score 2):

I tried out the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056681/count-multiple-rows-in-mssql-query/1056705#1056705) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056681/count-multiple-rows-in-mssql-query/1056707#1056707) just for my own edification, and thought I'd share the results in case it helps anyone else. The dataset is small, but shows the principle.

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM transactions;
id          type_id      status_id
----------  ----------   ----------
1           insurance    completed
2           insurance    declined
3           cheque-stop  completed
4           cheque-stop  completed

sqlite> SELECT
   ...>     type_id,
   ...>     SUM(status_id == 'completed') AS completed,
   ...>     SUM(status_id == 'declined') AS declined
   ...> FROM transactions
   ...> GROUP BY type_id;
type_id      completed   declined
-----------  ----------  ----------
cheque-stop  2           0
insurance    1           1
```

Comment: why do i get this error :Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: I guess, this would be mysql syntax. OP is asking for TSQL syntax.

Comment: @Andreas: My example is from SQLite3, a different db engine than Microsoft's SQL Server.

Comment: if you see my answer below, i get repeated rows for zero results any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need another WHERE clause in your sub queries linking the TRANSACTION_TYPE_IDs up.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, YEAR(CREATED_ON)AS YEAR, MONTH(CREATED_ON)AS MONTH ,
(SELECT Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID)  FROM ONLINE_TRANSACTION 
 WHERE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID ='COMPLETED'AND MONTH(CREATED_ON)='2'
    AND TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=ot.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) AS COMPLETED,
(SELECT Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) FROM ONLINE_TRANSACTION 
 WHERE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID ='DECLINED'AND MONTH(CREATED_ON)='2'
    AND TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=ot.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) AS DECLINED,
(SELECT Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) from ONLINE_TRANSACTION
 WHERE  ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID ='FAILED' AND MONTH(CREATED_ON)='2'
    AND TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=ot.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) AS FAILED,
(SELECT Count(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) from ONLINE_TRANSACTION
 WHERE  ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID ='PENDING_AUTH'AND MONTH(CREATED_ON)='2'
    AND TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=ot.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID) AS PENDING_AUTH
FROM ONLINE_TRANSACTION ot
WHERE MONTH(CREATED_ON)='2'
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID,ONLINE_TRANSACTION.CREATED_ON
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clauses in the nested select statements don't distinguish between the different transaction types. The numbers are always the total amounts.

Try looking into sum and case.

```
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, YEAR(CREATED_ON)AS YEAR, MONTH(CREATED_ON)AS MONTH ,
  SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID WHEN 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COMPLETED,
  SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID WHEN 'DECLINED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECLINED,
  SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID WHEN 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FAILED,
  SUM(CASE ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID WHEN 'PENDING_AUTH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PENDING_AUTH
FROM ONLINE_TRANSACTION WHERE MONTH(CREATED_ON)='2'
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthetical `SELECT`s in your main `SELECT` clause go back to the total `ONLINE_TRANSACTION` table so of course they're getting their counts without regards to the type, but rather overall!

What about changing each of them into a `SUM` (over the same grouping you already have, so no extra syntax needed) of the `STATUS_ID` checks -- taking 1 for equality and 0 for difference (that bool to 0/1 int conversion is automatic in many SQL dialects, at worst you'll need an `IF` or `CASE...WHEN` or `CAST` for that, whatever your dialect of choice).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, YEAR(CREATED_ON) AS YEAR, MONTH(CREATED_ON) AS MONTH , 
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'DECLINED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Declined,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'PENDING_AUTH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pending_Auth
FROM ONLINE_TRANSACTION
WHERE MONTH(CREATED_ON) = 2
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, YEAR(CREATED_ON), MONTH(CREATED_ON)
```

See if this makes sense.

Comment: I HAVE TRIED THIS BUT I GET THE FOLLOWING:

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: That is surprising. Try removing SUM clauses except 1 and see if that works.

Comment: are you still having problem with above SQL?

Comment: i am inddeed i get repeating rows when no results are present (instead of showing it in one row) i have added added comments in the question above

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your sample data & result after you run the query that I gave above?